# Django popup box Error?? Running development web server

Tags: python, django, webserver

I have my Django site up and running, and everything works fine EXCEPT:

When I first go to my site http://127.0.0.1:8000

A popup box comes up and says

"The page at http://127.0.0.1:8000 says"

And just sits there

You have to hit OK before anything is displayed.

What is going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must have a Javascript alert box in your template somewhere.